# Plot fragments from a science fiction compilation that I have forgotten and would like to find

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

So there's a compilation of science fiction short stories I had when I was a kid that I lost and can't remember the name of, nor any of the names of the stories or authors. I just remember some plot fragments, probably incorrectly. Overmind, please help me remember and find this stuff.  I probably read it around 1981-1982, so the stories would date from before that -- probably from the 70s.

- **Plot fragment #1**: Some guy finds another guy (maybe named Aldus) with an apparent mental age of 7 who lives/hangs out in a junkyard -- except Aldus somehow cobbles together a device from junkyard parts that glows and can mysteriously levitate. However, something pisses Aldus off, so he takes it apart before anybody can figure out how he has done it. All he ever says, softly, is "Whee!"
- **Plot fragment #2**: A guy lives and works in a line of people who are all passing building stones down the line to one another, bucket-brigade style. He has always lived and worked in this line. He has nictitating membranes. He notes to a coworker that the bones of their ancestors were visibly different. I'm not sure we ever find out what these generations of people are building.
- **Plot fragment #3**: A bum in poor health eats something that he thinks is food. It isn't; it's a teleportation device, and he manages to turn it on with one of his remaining teeth on its way down. He becomes ravenously hungry and can eat giant, impossible quantities of food (he might win a hard-boiled egg eating contest, but maybe that was only in Cool Hand Luke). Also, his health improves. Then, whoever is on the other end of the teleportation device decides they have enough of what he is sending, and they start sending other stuff back.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @MartinSchröder, perhaps he wants to accept his own answer below. If so, he has to wait two days.

Answer (score 17):

I was able to identify the compilation: [13 Great Stories of Science Fiction](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1179647.13_Great_Stories_of_Science_Fiction), published 1960, edited by Groff Conklin.

[image]

Comment: If anyone else is interested, it looks like #2 was "The War is Over" by Algis Budrys (summarized at http://mporcius.blogspot.com/2014/08/1950s-stories-from-algis-budrys-arthur.html ), and #3 was "Shipping Clerk" by William Morrison (can be read in its entirety at http://bookre.org/reader?file=262439 )

Comment: Nice team effort.

Comment: @SeanDuggan, you have to wait two days before accepting your own answer.

Comment: It sounds like the greatest short stories of Science Ficion, a twice yearly series of books (each on focusing on a year starting in 1939) by Asimov and Martin H. Greenburg.  Worth checking out.  I know the first story is in one of them.  I have so many collections though, it's hard to determine where I saw them first.

Comment: Ah, right you are, Paul.

Comment: ^_^ But now perhaps?

Answer (score 16):

Plot fragment #1 is from the story ["The Available Data on the Worp Reaction"](http://books.google.com/books?id=1M0Y2RYqffIC&lpg=PA174&ots=T2EgCiqZrt&dq=The%20Available%20Data%20on%20the%20Worp%20Reaction&pg=PA174#v=onepage&q=The%20Available%20Data%20on%20the%20Worp%20Reaction&f=false) (Google Books) by Lion Miller. 
An [audio version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGU-65qMRJE) of the story is currently available on YouTube.

Comment: Here's a list of compilations it's appeared in, which might help finding the other two: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74061